# Script type module doesn't work when injected into iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, es6-modules

I'm trying to leverage modules to dynamically attach variables on iframe's Window.

The problem is, that when I'm doing simple `iframe.contentDocument.write(html)`, with script of `type='module'`, the script inside iframe won't run.
If i use script without `type='module'`, the script runs (and for example logs something to console)

Why am I unable to inject module scripts into an iframe like this? Is this some layer of security I am not aware of?

Edit:
Here is piece of code i'm injecting, i checked the network tab, and browser fetches the dependency from public directory, `console.log()` doesn't run though

```
<script type="module">
      import * as materialuicore from "/.vite/@material-ui_core.js"
      console.log('materialuicore')
      if (!window.__deps) window.__deps = {}

      window.__deps["@material-ui/core"] = materialuicore
    </script>
```

Comment: `contentDocument.write(html)` - why are you using that awful, deprecated, atrocious function?

Comment: "Why i am unable to inject module scripts into iframe like this?" JavaScript modules don't run inline in a page, so there is no still-loading document content stream to write raw text into.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: @Dai i updated the info. Looks like the module scripts won't run when injected with document.write(), not only inside iframe, but on main window too