# (Vue/Vite) script type="module" not running when loaded in iframe

Tags: vue.js, iframe, vite

I'm experimenting with Vite, VueJS 3 and [vite-plugin-singlefile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-singlefile) for an app which is bundled to a single HTML file, and then served **inside a sandboxed iframe** through a parent site I don't have much control to change.

Specifically, the iframe runs sandboxed with `<iframe src="someotherorigin/page.html" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms">`. My built HTML page references some external scripts via CDN (e.g. Bootstrap, etc), but the actual app code itself is inlined.

The app works fine with Vite's dev server and build+serve option. It's also fine when I preview in other tools... But in the target environment it seems like the main entrypoint script simply doesn't run. Nothing renders but also no error messages in console. I do get a couple of *warnings* about malformed CSP, but that's all:

```
Content Security Policy: Interpreting none as a hostname, not a keyword. If you intended this to be a keyword, use 'none' (wrapped in single quotes).
Content Security Policy: Interpreting https://none as a hostname, not a keyword. If you intended this to be a keyword, use 'none' (wrapped in single quotes).
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68013470/script-type-module-doesnt-work-when-injected-into-iframe) got me curious so I tried manually editing the **built** `index.html` to change the inlined `<script type="module">...</script>` to `<script>...</script>` - And it works fine!

...But:

1. I can't make that change in the **source** `index.html` (Vite just ignores & refuses to bundle the TypeScript `/src/main.ts` source unless "module" is set)
2. I don't think there's an easy way to automate changing it in the build pipeline either (seems like it'd be messing around with custom Vite plugins)
3. I don't really understand what's wrong in the first place - why would `type="module"` cause the iframe not to run this Vue-generated script? Is there some other more proper fix?